# how to get variable from form load to action?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
private void showCategory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string categoryId = "100"
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = categoryId;
}
```

how to pass string `categoryId` from form load to button click?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Windows Forms application than using the variable on the class level, not in the function

```
public partial class showCategory : Form
{
    string categoryId = null;

    private void showCategory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.categoryId = "100";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = this.categoryId;
    }
}
```

If it's Web Application - store the value the some state callection: ViewState, Session, HiddenField and so on..

Comment: Having it global class member will work in web application as well, the `Page_Load` is always executed before button click event so the variable will be assigned.

Comment: Would still be useful to know though, to tag the question properly. :)

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know where it used WinForms or Web, or somewhere else :)